# MongoDB text search function

Tags: mongodb

Maybe I am slow, but I am looking at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/

The question is, let's say I want to do a text search for:

```
word1 AND (word2 OR word3) AND word4 AND (word5 OR word6)
```

I do not see a way to do that. If I pass

```
"\"word1\" word2 word3" will do word1 AND (word2 OR word3)
```

if I do

```
"\"word4\" word5 word6" will do word4 AND (word5 OR word6)
```

but if I put them together

```
"\"word1\" word2 word3 \"word4\" word5 word6"
```

this will give me word1 AND word2 AND (word3 OR word4 or word5 or word6)
which is not what I want.

Am I missing something, how do I concatenate the searches?

Comment: Are you sure about that? On first read I thought you were looking for an **`$or`** comparison, which presently you cannot do. But reading again, I think you are confusing the meaning of whatever follows \"word1\" to be the AND. The actual meaning should be "word1" and "word4" must contain ( so AND)  with the rest of the words as the logical OR. Which is what your original statement logically expands to. Unless you actually do mean an **`$or`** type comparison, but that isn't what your first statement says.

Comment: Maybe I am confusing the issues. I want to do a search for documents that contain both word1 and word4 and either word2 or word3 and either word5 and word6. Is that possible?